# Unterstanding flutter Navigation

Tags: navigation, dart, flutter

I am using Fluro but I think that doesn't matter in this case.

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` with two different icons. On each tab I want to use the navigator to go the other route. Is it possible to use the Navigator to set a route without any animation and back button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Navigator` is used only to navigate between two different routes (Say completely two different screens or views). `BottomNavigationBar` does not take us to new screen but is used to change the view of current route. You can achieve it many ways.

An example with `PageView`:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Example",
    home: new BottomNav(),
  ));
}

class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavState createState() => new _BottomNavState();
}

class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {
  PageController _controller = new PageController();

  int _currentPage = 0;

  void _onBottomNavChange(int index) {
    _controller.animateToPage(index,
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease);
    setState(() {
      _currentPage = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new PageView(controller: _controller, children: [
        new Container(color: Colors.red),
        new Container(color: Colors.blue),
      ]),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_left), title: new Text("Left")),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_right), title: new Text("Right")),
        ],
        onTap: _onBottomNavChange,
        currentIndex: _currentPage,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can take a look at another example [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/bottom_navigation_demo.dart), which uses `Stack` for `BottomNavigationBar` actions.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks! It was a misunderstanding of what the navigator does